# wp_dropdown_categories doesn't list all categories

Tags: php, wordpress, list, categories

**my code is:**

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=select&&tab_index=4&taxonomy=category' ); ?>
```

I have 3 categories but it lists only the "general" catagory.
what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=select&&tab_index=4&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
```